# How can I make height of div with a background image based on it's width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div of class `content`:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: URL("img/main.png") center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I want that div along with the image inside to automatically resize based on it's container size (body) so I have defined width 100% and I want height to adapt and keep the aspect ratio.

Problem is that if I don't set any height in pixels, the image doesn't appear ever. Is there a way to do so?

Basically what I want to achieve is auto resizing like on this page: http://ketrawars.com/

Comment: Have a demo? I can only assume you're referring to the `body.ketra_main` background image in your example link.

Comment: There is no CSS property that can size an element to the size of a background image. You may have to rethink your methodology.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the height to be 100%, you will definitely achieve what you want.
check the below style.

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("images/image.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding  `min-height: 100%`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple jQuery code to do that

```
var width=$(".content").width();
$(".content").height(width);
```